# Changing from stereographic north pole to WGS 84?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, vector, arcgis-9.3

I'm trying to use a vector file created with these parameters in Esri ArcGIS 9.3.1.

```
Projected Coordinate System: Oblique_Stereographic
Projection: Stereographic_North_Pole
false_easting:  500000.0
false_northing: 500000.0
scale_factor:   0.99975
longitude_of_center: 25.0
latitude_of_center:  46.0
Linear Unit: Meter
```

Is there a way to convert/transform the vector file created in WGS 84?

There is the vector file: [elevation data](https://ufile.io/cgayt)

Comment: EPSG:7239 is for a coord operation in Indiana, USA, not a polar area.

Answer (score 3):

The definition you gave doesn't match EPSG:7239 which is a coordinate operation for a county in Indiana, USA. I edited the code/well-known ID out of the title question because it's misleading.

The projection parameters match a Romanian projected coordinate reference system. The current definition in EPSG is EPSG::3844, Pulkovo 1942(58) / Stereo70. In EPSG, the map projection algorithm is called Stereographic, but in Esri software it's called "Double Stereographic" because we already had a Stereographic projection prior to adopting the EPSG dataset. Esri also has an older version of the same projected coordinate reference system called "Stereo_70" and based on the geographic coordinate system, Dealul Piscului 1970. Basically, it's an alternative name for Pulkovo 1942(58). The WKID for this one is 31700.

Redefine the data to one of these using the Define Projection Tool.

Once you've done that, you can use the Project Tool to create a new dataset using WGS 1984 (EPSG:4326). If you use 31700, use "Dealul Piscului 1970 to WGS 1983 3X" as the geographic/datum transformation. If you use 3844, use Pulkovo 1942(58) to WGS 1984 (19) as the transformation.

The data with its current definition is unusable in Esri software because the coordinate reference system definition is not correct and won't give the correct coordinate values. If you try to overlay this data with other layers, it should not line up.

Disclosure: I am an Esri employee who focuses on coordinate reference systems and transformations. I'm also a member of the subcommittee that maintains the EPSG geodetic registry.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for correcting the topic. I've done the job using Define Projection Tool. Now the shapefile has Double_Stereographic Projection with Datum D_Pulkovo_1942. But the layer is still in the wrong place when I'm overlaying with a similar/another shp in Double_Stereographic Projection. My real issue was/is to represent the shp correctly in Stereo70. Is there any transformation from this stage which I should apply?

Comment: How far apart are they? Could be an issue with different geoCRS/datums if the offset is around 100 m or less or bad ProjCRS definition if offset is a lot larger.

Comment: Hello! It is pretty far in terms of tens of kilometers.

Comment: Here's my next request. If you unproject both versions (original definition, new one) does either one have the correct lat/lon values?

Comment: No, they do not have. The problem is that when the shp was created the projection was Stereographic_North_Pole. When the shapefile was overlapped over raster file (in StereoGraphic 1970) ESRI ArcView 9.3.1. projected on the fly and the layers "matched". After exporting or opening in a different GIS software (such as Global Mapper or Autodesk Map3d) the shapefile didn't "go" in the right extend.